# Passing argument 1 of 'fgets' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, fgets

I run this piece of code and i get the following error, i did some research but i didn't really got an answer i hope if someone of you could give me a little help. I am new to programming please spare me if i missed something too obvious.

> **[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'fgets' makes pointer from integer without a cast**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 char *t,*s;
 char first, second;
 int x;

 printf("Give the first string: ");
 fgets(first,sizeof(char),stdin);
 printf("Give the second string: ");
 fgets(second,sizeof(char),stdin);
}
```

When i add a "&" inside my "first" and "second" variables it compiles but when i run it i don't get the strings that i gave from the keyboard.

How to make it compile?

Comment: `first` is not an array...

Comment: Warnings are there for a reason

Comment: You are talking about the sizeof(char) part?

Comment: [An `fgets` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) might help you. Also, a single character is a single character. If you read the linked reference you will see that using `fgets` to read a single character actually needs an array of at least *three* characters: One for the actual character, one for the newline and one for the string terminator.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm wondering what the "_from integer_" part in the warning mean? I mean, the OP calls `fgets` with a `char` (not an `int`) as the first argument, right?

Comment: I run the fgets like that 

fgets(s, 25, stdin);
fgets(t, 25, stdin);

But the problem is that after i put in the first string the program exits with error

Comment: @Dimitris Because `s` and `t` are uninitialized meaning that it could be pointing anywhere. You therefore write into invalid memory locations you aren't supposed to tamper with, invoking a phenomenon called Undefined Behavior. This means that anything could've happened. The solution to this would be to make the pointers point to a valid memory location before calling `fgets`. Eg: `char str[100], *s = str; fgets(s /* or \`str\` directly */, 100, stdin)` or `char *s = malloc(100); if(s) fgets(s, 100, stdin); free(s);`. I hope this has shed some light on your confusion. :-)

Comment: @CoolGuy When a variable of a type smaller than `int` is used in an expression, the it's [*promoted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char first[80], second[80];

    printf("Give the first string: ");
    fgets(first, sizeof(char), stdin);
    printf("Give the second string: ");
    fgets(second, sizeof(char), stdin);
}
```

`fgets` means "get a **string** from a file", and you need an array of char to hold a string.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` expects `char*` pointing to a buffer as it's first argument

Comment: @Dimitris Yes. A pointer pointing to a valid memory location(`malloc`ed memory segment, an automatic character array)

Comment: @Dimitris yes, to a buffer, also take note that buffer also should have capacity for null-terminating character - so nothing will be read into a buffer of size 1. See some reference like http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Answer (score 0):

you should turn first and second into pointers and allocated space to fill them in

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int flen = 256;
int slen = 256;
 char* first = malloc(flen); //allocate enough space to handle verbose typists :)
 char* second = malloc(slen);
 int x;

 printf("%s\n","Give the first string: ");
 fgets(first,flen,stdin);

 printf("%s\n","Give the second string: ");
 fgets(second,slen,stdin);

//do something with first and second.

//free memory you allocated
free(first);
free(second);
};
```